# getline() с учетом перевода строки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шифрование

Сделал программу, которая отзеркаливает текст. Она работает, но когда я засунул ее в функцию, она перестала работать. А если точно, оно пропускает этап ввода и сразу выводит отзеркаленный текст(ничего).Как это пофиксить? Вот код в отдельном проекте `

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string original, final;

int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

cout << "Введите текст: " << endl;
getline(cin, original);

    for (int i = original.size(); i >= 0; i--) 
{
    final.push_back(original[i]);
}


cout << "Зашифрованное: " << final << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

И вот в функции: `

```
void Zerkalo() 
 {
string original, final;

cout << "Введите текст: " << endl;
getline(cin, original);

for (int i = original.size(); i >= 0; i--) 
{
    final.push_back(original[i]);
}

cout << "Зашифрованное: " << final << endl;

}`
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: Приведенная программа не соответствует скриншоту, в ней нет никакого "Что вы хотите выполнить"

Comment: Первый код это проект, где я писал сам код. Его я потом вставил в другой проект в функцию, но не важно. Ответ снизу мне помог @VTT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того, как ты ввёл `2`, в буфере консоли остался перевод строки. Вызов `getline` считывает с текущей позиции до конца строки - там находится пустая строка.

Чтобы этого не происходило, следует обеспечить, чтобы перевод строки там не оставался. Например, вызвать ту же `getline` и не использовать результат. Либо при считывании числа сразу промотаться до конца строки и считать его `scanf("%d%*[^\n]%*1[\n]", &x)`.

Comment: Хм, в коде автора вопроса происходит обращение к элементу строки `original` с индексом `original.size()`. Это допустимо или UB? И гарантируется ли корректный вывод строки `final`, если первым символом в ней будет `\0`?

Comment: @wololo, не уверен, но реально там будет 0 у строки.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы недопускать ошибок, не следует писать то, что уже написано и можно сделать попроще. Например:

```
void Zerkalo()
{
    string  final;
    cout << "Введите текст: " << endl;
    getline(cin, final);;
    std::reverse(final.begin(), final.end());    
    cout << "Зашифрованное: " << final << endl;
}
```