# Функция cin.getline()

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Объясните пожалуйста почему функция cin.getline() в данном коде игнорирует нулевой элемент массив строк?

```
void Filling(char **&Strings, int rows) {
cout << "Enter strings: " << endl;
for(int counter = 0; counter < rows; counter++)
    cin.getline(Strings[counter], 80);  
}
```

Strings это двумерный массив строк.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/782849/178988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вызов cin.getline() воспринимает endl перед циклом как введенный символ. Для исправления перед циклом вставьте cin.ignore().